# how to debug node.js application

Tags: node.js, debugging

I am working on a nodejs project. I am thinking, is it possible to debug nodejs code like the way debug JavaScript in browser. I mean is there any tool or plugin available to debug nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

^You can use node-inspector for debugging.

1) Start your node process in debug mode,
"node --debug-brk=5858 app.js"

2) Start node-inspector process with,
"nohup node-inspector &"

3) In your browser, go to:
http://127.0.0.1:9001/debug?port=5858 
and start debugging.